# Modify global parameter ADF pipeline

Tags: u-sql, azure-data-factory

How can I modify the value of a global parameter declared in a pipeline of an ADF?

Let's say I need to check whether or not a file in a ADLS exists. I declare a boolean global parameter, but according to my logic inside a U-SQL activity I need to modify its value. How can I do that?

Thanks!!!

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do where. 

Can you please provide a script fragment or more concrete example?

In U-SQL you can use FILE.EXISTS(path) in an IF statement. It will evaluate at compile time.

Comment: In Azure Data factory pipelines, parameters can be defined. I want to evaluate FILE.EXISTS(path), if it exists, then set the parameter to 1/true, otherwise set it to 0/false. Then outside I can evaluate this parameter to choose what to to next. The main issue here is, how to provide input parameters to u-sql activity in Data factory, and modify its value if it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

U-SQL's script parameter model only provides input parameters and no output parameters. If you want to communicate something back, you currently have to do this via a file. E.g., you write the file in the script and then use a Powershell activity to look at the file to set the ADF parameter (I assume that Data Factory has that option).